# Inconsistent data when querying the same dataset but with a timezone other than UTC in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

In the application I'm developing whenever a user clicks a certain link I log that click in the database with a timestamp. The server's timezone is UTC. I have a report section where I can query the database for different date intervals (today, yesterday, this week, last 7 days, year to date etc.) and I also have the possibility to select a timezone.

Now here comes the interesting part - when I select a timezone other than UTC, let's say America/New_York I get different values for "today" versus the same day in a date interval. For example if I query for "2020-03-02" I get 200 hits. If I query for "2020-03-01 - 2020-03-08" I get 179 hits for "2020-03-02".

I think I know where this is coming from, but the inconsistency is driving me crazy.

I believe is coming from the fact that when I select a timezone I get an X hours offset. For example for America/New_York I have a +5 hours offset so "2020-03-02 00:02:01" UTC becomes "2020-03-01 19:02:01" for America/New_York

In SQL I'm using the CONVERT_TZ() function when querying, like so:

```
SELECT h.id, h.income, h.created, u.email, u.referer 
FROM hits h
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = h.id
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(h.created, 'UTC', 'America/New_York') BETWEEN '2020-03-02 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-02 23:59:59' -- single day
ORDER BY h.income DESC

SELECT h.id, h.income, h.created, u.email, u.referer 
FROM hits h
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = h.id
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(h.created, 'UTC', 'America/New_York') BETWEEN '2020-03-001 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-07 23:59:59' -- custom period
ORDER BY h.income DESC
```

So is it possible to have consistent number of hits for the same date when querying for a timezone other than UTC? Basically if "today" means ""2020-03-02" and has 200 hits I want to see the same number of this when querying for "2020-03-01 - 2020-03-08".

Comment: Are you using TIMESTAMP or DATETIME? The former doesn't have a TZ attached and uses the system current time.

Comment: I'm using DATETIME and it's fine to save the date of the click using the system time. This is by design. Only the reporting needs to be on other timezone.

Comment: *So is it possible to have consistent number of hits for the same date when querying for a timezone other than UTC*: days do not start at the same time everywhere in the world, so daily results cannot be consistent across timezones. If you want something consistent, stick to UTC - or to a given timezone.

Comment: He's not looking for consistency *across* timezones, he wants it within the same date in the same timezone whether he's querying for a single date or a range. Cosmin, can you show us how you construct your SQL queries in both cases?

Comment: @El_Vanja, I have updated my original post with the queries I have. They are pretty simple, nothing fancy.